# Summing every 3 elements in list aside from 0-- Python

Tags: python, list, sum, slice

I am having trouble with the following problem (working in Python):

With any given list, the goal is to sum all elements that are nonzero with 3 being the maximum number of elements summed. After summing the elements, the sum would replace the first element and the other two elements (out of the three that were summed) are replaced with 0. We will leave all elements that are 0 in place.

For example:

```
Input:   a = [2, 5, 0, 7, 6, 5, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8]
Output:  a = [7, 0, 0,18, 0, 0, 0, 0,21, 0, 0]
```

Another example--

```
Input: a = [0,6,0,0,7,9,8,9,8,0,0,2]
Desired output-- a = [0,6,0,0,24,0,0,17,0,0,0,2]
```

Comment: Did you try to code at all?

Comment: Yes, I've spent quite some time on it this morning... Unfortunately Im very new to this so Im having difficulties and felt like the code I did write is useless because I keep getting error after error :/ I can sort through all of my attempts and post one of them that seems to be the most on track but it might not be of any help tbh

Comment: I formatted the first example for better readability, I suggest you do the same with the second one.

Comment: We have to see that you have made a good-faith effort to solve this.  This looks like homework.

Comment: Thank you @KellyBundy! Sorry-- new here and wasn't sure how to make it look more user-friendly. I appreciate it :)

Comment: @TimRoberts very fair! I am sorting through the (sadly lol) many many attempts I've done and am trying to find something that seems even kinda on track. This isn't homework, promise! Lol

Comment: I don't understand the second example.  If "the sum would replace the first element", then why is the first element still zero?

Comment: I probably should've phrased it as "the sum of the first element of the three being summed"... So for the second example the first element of the (theoretically) three being summed is 6

Comment: "the sum of the first element of the three being summed" also makes no sense.  Why are you summing _one_ element?

Comment: The amount of elements being summed is dynamic, it could be one element or it could be up to three elements. This is why I said theoretically in my last comment... Since the two elements after the 6 are 0, they should not *technically* be included in the summation (zeros should be left alone), even though 6+0+0 still equals 6

Answer (score 0):

Solution that also handles the corner case [1, 0, 2, 0] -> [1, 0, 2, 0]

**Code**

```
def func(arr, n = 3):
    # Group elements into non-zero sublists with of length at most 3
    # Or One element sublist with value 0
    group = []
    for i in arr:
        if not group or i == 0 or group[-1][-1] == 0 or len(group[-1])==n:
            group.append([i])
        else:
            group[-1].append(i)
    
    # Flatten each group by summing as first element with remaining 0
    return [sum(sublist) if i == 0 else 0 for sublist in group for i, x in enumerate(sublist)]
```

**Tests**

```
print(func([2, 5, 0, 7, 6, 5, 0 , 0, 6, 7, 8])) 
#Output: [7, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0, 21, 0, 0]

print(func([0,6,0,0,7,9,8,9,8,0,0,2]))  
# Output: [0, 6, 0, 0, 24, 0, 0, 17, 0, 0, 0, 2]

print(func([1, 0, 2, 0]))
# Output: [1, 0, 2, 0]
```